# Who is the character who Spud reports as dead?

Tags: t2-trainspotting

Note: "X" is none of the main characters.

In Trainspotting-2, after Renton meets Spud, Spud tells him that "X is dead" and Renton answer that he did not expect him to be still alive.

I did not get the name, I guess it would be one of the secondary characters of Trainspotting 1 but I cannot tell who would it be.

Who is (was) X?

Comment: I think it was Mikey - the drug dealer character played by Irvine Welsh. The only other named character it could be is Swanney played by Peter Mullan but I don't remember this character from the first film.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The character you are looking for is **Swanney** played by Peter Mullan in the first movie.
But this dialogue is not between Mark and Spud but **between Mark and Simon** (Sick Boy) at approximately 31 minutes during the scene where they are remembering their first heroin hit together.

> "Swanney's dead now, of course." (Simon)
>
> "Be astonished if he wasn't." (Mark)

Answer (score 1):

I think he refers to Swanney aka "Mother superior". If I remember correctly he was their friend/dealer.
As mentionned in a comment, the character was played by Peter Mullan.